# How to load external es6 script module in Magento

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, xml

Is it possible to add a script tag with the attribute type set to module e.g. type="module" in magento?

I'm trying to load a es6 module through the head of the xml file but it is not retrieving the script with the type module set.

This is the code:

[image]

This is the resultant script, as you can see the type attribute is being replaced with type="script/text"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not add type=module via xml. But here have an alternatives. You can create a block and add your script in template.phtml file after that assign this block into head section.

[you can see this article for better understanding.](https://php-scripts-form.blogspot.com/2023/06/loading-external-es6-script-modules-in.html) https://php-scripts-form.blogspot.com/2023/06/loading-external-es6-script-modules-in.html

```
<head>
    <block class="Your\Module\Block\CustomScript" name="custom_script" template="Your_Module::custom_script.phtml" />
</head>
```

In the custom_script.phtml file, add your script tag with the type="module" attribute:

```
<script type="module">
    // Your ES6 module code here
</script>
```